# Log struct variable to file in trace32

Tags: trace32

I am trying to log the contents of a structure to a file with a practice script.

I would rather not use Var.VALUE for every field of the struct and so far I have found the Var.PRINT command which displays all the information contained in the struct.

However I do not know if I can output this to a file, or if there is any other solution I'm not aware of for logging the values of a struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These three scripts can log the contents of a structure.

**cmm1**

```
PRinTer.FILE c:\temp\temp1.txt
WinPrint.v.v struct_name
TYPE c:\temp\temp1.txt
ENDDO
```

**cmm2**

```
PRinTer.FILE c:\temp\temp2.txt
WinPrint.v.v %all struct_name
TYPE c:\temp\temp2.txt
ENDDO
```

**cmm3**

```
PRinTer.FILE c:\temp\temp3.txt
WinPrint.v.v %m.4 %r.5 struct_name
TYPE c:\temp\temp3.txt
ENDDO
```

The **cmm1** script will save the first level content.

The **cmm2** script will save the first level content along with data type.

The **cmm3** script will save the pointer value recursively.

**m** stands for **multiline**. It displays the structure elements in multiple line format. If the elements are in a multidimensional array, the numeric parameter  defines the number of levels displayed.

**r** stands for **recursive**.  This optional number defines the depth of recursion to be displayed. The command SETUP.VarPtr defines the valid address range for pointers. The contents of pointers outside this range are not displayed.

Comment: `WinPrint` or `Var.WRITE`  can only write up to 4095 bytes to the file at a time. For larger size structures, this method may lose some data. Is there a command that allows us to get each element inside the structure and then use `WinPrint` or `Var.WRITE` to write each element to the file?